# How to store elements in a list of String array in a java array?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have data stored in a list of String array (`List<String[]> data = reader.readAll();`) and I'm trying to store them in a java array (value). Please see the below code. data is getting stored in the array "value" but it's getting replaced all the time and it will show the last value only at the end of the loop. I need to store all the data in an array without replacing. Please help me to resolve this.

```java
String csvfile = "C:\\Users\\…….TestData\\LoginData.csv";

CSVReader reader= new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));

List<String[]> data = reader.readAll();

String[] values = new String[5] ;

try {     
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        values= data.get(i);
        System.out.println(values[1]); //second element is replaced by first
    }
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not be able to easily convert `List<String[]>` to `String[]` since they have different dimensions. It is like when you render 3d scene on a raster you miss the information about objects' depth.

In your case you can convert `List<String[]>` to `String[][]` (2d-array) without missing dimension aspect.

```
String[][] values = data.toArray(new String[][]{});
```

Running code in debug shows that conversion was performed successfully:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the element isn't  replaced in your code, you only print always the first element.

This how you can add the elements from a list into an array in java:

```
List data = new ArrayList();
data.addAll(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));

String[] values = new String[data.size()];
int index = 0;
for (Object s : data) {
      values[index] = s.toString();
      index++;
}

for (String s: values)System.out.println(s);
```